# How to remove the blank page when omitting comments and messages in knitr

Tags: knitr

I am using the following code to create a plot, I want to omit message, comments and warnings and everything else but the plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

<<echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, comment=NA, warning=FALSE>>=
x1 <- runif(10)
y1 <- runif(10)
x2 <- runif(10)
y2 <- runif(10)
x <- cbind(x1,x2)
y <- cbind(y1,y2)
plot(y ~ x)
@

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

A blank page is created before the plot. I think there is something related to the landscape that create the blank page. Is there any way to get rid of it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with knitr. A file with just the following lines: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}\includegraphics{figure/unnamed-chunk-1} \end{landscape}
\end{document}` still creates a blank page. It appears to be the fault of `pdf1scape`.

Comment: Yes it is, I have reported the issue to latex. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I'm unable to reproduce the problem you suggest. Using your MWE produces a single page in landscape format *without* a blank page inserted.

Comment: @Werner: How large is your figure (what I put as figure/unnamed-chunk-1)? I've noticed it depends on the figure size. The defaults from knitr appear (to me) to lead to a blank page.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: This may be the cause, since I inserted content that could fit within the text block boundary.

Comment: Related question, [errors - Blank pages getting inserted between figures - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286037/250119)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is too large (doesn't fit within the text block defined by `\textwidth` and `\textheight`), it will cause an overfull box warning, initiate a page break and roll over onto a subsequent page. If the default behaviour of your document construction causes this overflow, the following would take care of discarding the first page (always):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,atbegshi,pdflscape}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,atbegshi,pdflscape}
\AtBeginShipout{\ifnum\value{page}=1\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{example-image-a}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) provides `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard` which discards the currently stored page and should be executed `\AtBeginShipout`. We test for the value of the `page` counter and discard the page if its 1. The above document produces a single page, despite the two-page output caused by the oversized image.

---

If you have this problem only sometimes and want to automate the procedure, you should use the [`lastpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) to keep track of the last page within your document. If that last page is anything other than 1, discard the first page. Here's a take on that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,atbegshi,pdflscape}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,atbegshi,pdflscape}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lastpage,refcount}
\newcounter{lastpage}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \setcounterpageref{lastpage}{LastPage}
  \ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
    \ifnum\value{lastpage}>1\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi\fi}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{example-image-a}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The [`refcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) bridges the gap between references and counters by allowing one to assign *values* of the former to the latter.

Ps. I've used [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics` in order to place an image of oversized proportions. Your use in `knitr` would be similar but may not require this package.